# Weight capacity of a 1-1/4" trailer axle?

Tags: axle, trailer, weight

I just got a used trailer, it has a 1-1/4" square dropped axle. The seller said it was good for a 3500lb capacity, and that it was a solid core. I'm skeptical of that.

How do I tell what the true capacity is?

I'm hoping that it will at least hold 2500lbs, but I can easily resell it if not.

Comment: The bearings , wheels and tires  will have as much to do with capacity as the axel.

Comment: The ball size of the coupler will also be a factor.

Comment: See if it has manufacturer's label on the axle itself or the trailer.  If not, then your guess is as good as mine.  Alternatively you should see if you can find an axle at a retailer that is similar in design and construction and see what its rating is.  That will still be a guess but a better informed one.

Comment: See this, probably a 1,000lb axle.>>>>https://www.etrailer.com/question-18434.html